# python- table missing when there's an image attachment in email

Tags: python, smtp

I followed a guide to have embedded picture in my email. After attaching this piece to my msg, I attached a dataframe's html format. The picture shows up fine in sent email, however, the table is completely missing.

```
        with open (attachment, 'rb') as f:
            mime = MIMEBase ('image', 'png', filename='img1.png')
            mime.add_header ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='img1.png')
            mime.add_header ('X-Attachment-Id', '0')
            mime.add_header ('Content-ID', '<0>')
            mime.set_payload (f.read ())
            encoders.encode_base64 (mime)
            msg.attach (mime)
        f.close()

        msg.attach (MIMEText (
            '<h><img src="cid:0"></h>' ,'html', 'utf-8'))


        data =  pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]})
        data_html = "<body>"+ data.to_html()+"</body>"
        msg.attach(MIMEText (data_html , 'html'))
```

I tried the multipart attach as well (for table, attach as 'plain' then attach as 'html'), does not work.
I tried setting img at header, body, and paragraph level, but none seems to bring my table below to show up.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

so I just figured out how to bypass it.
Instead of attaching

```
'<img src="cid:0">'
```

to the msg, I appended this piece to the html string like

```
htmlf = "<body>"+"<td>"+'<img src="cid:0">'+ "</td>"+data.to_html()+"</body>"
```

and it worked.

Still have no idea why attaching separately didn't work though.